# dyld not found AVAssetDownladTask

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, http-live-streaming, avassetdownloadtask

Trying to add offline HLS (a new ios 10 feature) to an app.  I'm trying the following in swift in order for the app to still function on ios 9 without the offline HLS Functionality.  Works fine on ios10 and compiles for ios9 too.

```
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    @objc class DownloadManager: NSObject, AVAssetDownloadDelegate {
           //Do stuff with downloading assets
      }
```

However, when I actually run this on a ios 9 device, the app crashes immediately with the following message :

> dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAssetDownloadTask   Referenced
>   from:
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7062C410-C4F5-4270-9F1E-22750E99F799/wod.app/wod
>   Expected in:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation  in
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7062C410-C4F5-4270-9F1E-22750E99F799/wod.app/wod

I've constrained all code related to this to the DownloadManager class so i dunno what to do next.  Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to weak link AVFoundation.  Found it on apple's site.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html

> Weak Linking to Entire Frameworks
>
> When you reference symbols in another framework, most of those symbols
>   are linked strongly to your code. In order to create a weak link to a
>   symbol, the framework containing the symbol must explicitly add the
>   weak_import attribute to it (see Marking Symbols for Weak Linking).
>   However, if you do not maintain a framework and need to link its
>   symbols weakly, you can explicitly tell the compiler to mark all
>   symbols as weakly linked. To do this, you must open your project in
>   Xcode and modify the way your targets link to the framework as
>   follows:
>
> Select the target you want to modify and reveal its build phases.
>   Expand the Link Binary With Libraries build phase to view the
>   frameworks currently linked by the target. If the framework you want
>   to weakly link to is listed in the Link Binary With Libraries build
>   phase, select it, and choose Edit > Delete to remove it. Now you can
>   tell the linker to use weak linking for that framework.
>
> Select the target, open its Info window, and click Build. To the Other
>   Linker Flags build setting, add the following command-line option
>   specification, where  is the name of the framework you
>   want to weakly link to:
>   -weak_framework  Build your product.

Comment: so the solution is: 
add AVFoundation to 'Link Binary With Libraries' with optional setting?

Comment: No it's not, (or it's not what I did at least) The steps are described in the the link and the comment I posted.

Answer (score 6):

I had same issue and I weak linked the AVFoundation framework
Below is the step

add **-weak_framework** AVfoundation in "other linker flags" in Build settings

Answer (score 1):

This picture shows how to weak link a framework:

[image: how to weak link a framework]